# Incorrect Time Offset in JavaScript Date() Function

Tags: javascript

Using the JavaScript Date() function on my phone, it returns the incorrect time for my location.  I receive PDT corrected time when in EDT.  This is on Android using Chrome.

I attempted to find documentation on how the function actually acquires the time offset to no avail.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It'll usually just use your system clock.

Comment: Interesting, because my Android system time is accurate.  Any insight on how it could possibly be getting the offset so wrong?